# Inno Installer - Why does it modify exe properties to require admin privileges and XP compatibility mode

Tags: inno-setup

An installation kit built with Inno installs two EXE files.  After installation, one file requires only normal user privileges.  The second file is marked with properties which require Admin privilges and XP compatibility mode.

The original EXE files have no visible properties set which would require Admin privileges or XP compatibility mode, and run fine on a Windows 7 box in normal user mode.  The second file was originally compiled on an XP system - but seems to run correctly when I copy it (without the installer) to the Windows 7 system.

When the installer script specifies "PrivilegesRequired=none", I still get a modified icon with the "Admin Privilege Required" marker and a file property set to "disable visual themes" for the installed EXE file.

The Inno version is 5.5.0(a)

How to I get the installer to copy the EXE files without changing their properties?

```
#define InstallRoot "D:\InstallationSource\Tracker\"
#define AppRoot "C:\Tracker\"
......

[Setup]
;directories
SourceDir={#InstallRoot}
DefaultDirName={#AppRoot}
.......

[Files]
Source: "*"; DestDir: "C:\Tracker\"; Flags: recursesubdirs
```

The executables are in a "bin" subdirectory under the main application directory.

Comment: what's the name of the files included. As Miral says in his response, it may be related to the file names.

Answer (score 2):

Inno doesn't change those properties.  They are set on a per-user basis according to the filename of the .exe file, irrespective of what directory it is in.  Thus if you have chosen something too generic for your .exe filename (eg. "setup.exe" or "app.exe") then you might be getting compatibility settings from some other application.

It's possible that if your installer name is generic (again, "setup.exe") then Windows might be trying to be "helpful" by copying the compatibility settings that it inherited across to any applications that it installed.

Either way, pick unique filenames.